# React Native reset to in nested navigators

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I'm currently building an app with a tabview that looks like this :

[image]

The code is the following :

**TabView.js**

```
resetToTab(index, opts) {
  var selected = this.state.selected;
  this.setState({selected: index});

  this.refs.tabs.jumpTo(this.refs.tabs.state.routeStack[index]);

  this.props.onTab(index);
};

renderScene = (tab, navigator) => {
  return (
    <Navigator
      style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}
      initialRoute={tab.component.route()}
      ref="views"
      renderScene={(route, nav) => {
        return React.createElement(route.component, _.extend({navigator: nav}, route.passProps));
      }}
      configureScene={() => {
        return {
          ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
          defaultTransitionVelocity: 1000,
          gestures: {}
        };
      }} />
  );
};

render() {
  return (
   <View style={styles.tabbarContainer}>
        <Navigator
        style={{backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'}}
        initialRouteStack={this.props.tabs}
        initialRoute={this.props.tabs[this.props.initialSelected || 0]}
        ref="tabs"
        key="navigator"
        renderScene={this.renderScene}
        configureScene={() => {
          return {
            ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid,
            defaultTransitionVelocity: 10000,
            gestures: {}
          };
        }} />

      {this.state.showTabBar ? [
                <View key="tabBar" style={styles.tabbarTabs}>
            {_.map(this.props.tabs, (tab, index) => {
            return this.renderTab(index, tab.name, tab.icon, tab.pastille, tab.hasShared);
            })}
        </View>
      ] : []}
    </View>
  );
};
```

**main.js**

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TabView 
        ref="tabs"
        onTab={(tab) => {
          this.setState({tab});
        }}
        tabs={[
          {
            component: Liste,
            name: 'Découvrir',
            icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/home.png')
          },
          {
            component: Friends,
            name: 'Amis',
            icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/friend.png'),
            pastille: this.state.friendsPastille < 10 ? this.state.friendsPastille : '9+'
          },
          {
            component: RecoStep1,
            icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/add.png'),
            hasShared: MeStore.getState().me.HAS_SHARED
          },
          {
            component: Notifs,
            name: 'Notifs',
            icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/notif.png'),
            pastille: this.state.notifsPastille < 10 ? this.state.notifsPastille : '9+'
          },
          {
            component: Profil,
            name: 'Profil',
            icon: require('../assets/img/tabs/icons/account.png')
          }
        ]}
        initialSkipCache={!!this.notifLaunchTab}
        initialSelected={this.notifLaunchTab || 0}
        tabsBlocked={false} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Only, when tapping on the bottom menu items, I jump back to the correct route but the navigator in render scene is not reset to the first view. I've tried to access `this.refs.views` but it's is undefined. When resetToTab is called, I'd like to be able to do something like `this.refs.views.resetTo(this.props.tabs[selected].component.route())` only `this.refs.views` is undefined. I'm pretty stuck on this one.